# WPF handling events overlay object

Tags: events, xaml

I have a some grids with a overlay canvas on top. The canvas is transparent and I can only handle mouse events on this canvas.

The problem is that I want to handle mouseDownEvents on the appropriate Grid object instead of the canvas.

I have experimented with routed events  and tried to route events deeper in the WPF tree by handling events at the grid that are already handled by the canvas:
grid.AddHandler(Grid.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(EducationMouseDown), true);

I also tried to set the Handled property of the eventArgs to false in the handler of the canvas.

Unfortunately, non of these attemps worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `IsHitTestVisible="false"` on your overlay canvas.

Comment: This works, but it is not a solution to my problem. With the isHitTestVisible property set to False the mousemove, mouseEnter and mouseLeave events are not detected on my canvas....

Comment: I misunderstood the question then. You want event on both the Canvas and the Grid? One has to be the child of the other if you want events to be raised on both (assuming they're not handled), they can't be on top of each other.